# Fixing hierarchy data with table transformation (Hive, scala, spark)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hierarchy

I have a task with working with hierarchical data, but the source data contains errors in the hierarchy, namely: some parent-child links are broken. I have an algorithm for reestablishing such connections, but I have not yet been able to implement it on my own.
Example:
Initial data is

```
+------+----+----------+-------+
| NAME | ID | PARENTID | LEVEL |
+------+----+----------+-------+
| A1   |  1 | 2        |     1 |
| B1   |  2 | 3        |     2 |
| C1   | 18 | 4        |     3 |
| C2   |  3 | 5        |     3 |
| D1   |  4 | NULL     |     4 |
| D2   |  5 | NULL     |     4 |
| D3   | 10 | 11       |     4 |
| E1   | 11 | NULL     |     5 |
+------+----+----------+-------+
```

Schematically it looks like:
[image]

As you can see, connections with C1 and D3 are lost here.
In order to restore connections, I need to apply the following algorithm for this table:

if for some NAME the ID is not in the PARENTID column (like ID = 18, 10), then create a row with a 'parent' with LEVEL = (current LEVEL - 1) and PARENTID = (current ID), and take ID and NAME such that the current ID < ID of the node from the LEVEL above.

Result must be like:

```
+------+----+----------+-------+
| NAME | ID | PARENTID | LEVEL |
+------+----+----------+-------+
| A1   |  1 | 2        |     1 |
| B1   |  2 | 3        |     2 |
| B1   |  2 | 18       |     2 |#
| C1   | 18 | 4        |     3 |
| C2   |  3 | 5        |     3 |
| C2   |  3 | 10       |     3 |#
| D1   |  4 | NULL     |     4 |
| D2   |  5 | NULL     |     4 |
| D3   | 10 | 11       |     4 |
| E1   | 11 | NULL     |     5 |
+------+----+----------+-------+
```

Where rows with # - new rows created.And new schema looks like:

[image]

Are there any ideas on how to do this algorithm in spark/scala? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a `createdRows` dataframe from your current dataframe that you union with your current dataframe to obtain your final dataframe.

You can build this `createdRows` dataframe in several step:

- The first step is to get the IDs (and LEVEL) that are not in PARENTID column. You can use a self left anti join to do that.
- Then, you rename`ID` column to `PARENTID` and updating `LEVEL` column, decreasing it by `1`.
- Then, you take `ID` and `NAME` columns of new rows by joining it with your input dataframe on the `LEVEL` column
- Finally, you apply your condition `ID` < `PARENTID`

You end up with the following code, `dataframe` is the dataframe with your initial data:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

val createdRows = dataframe
  // if for some NAME the ID is not in the PARENTID column (like ID = 18, 10)
  .select("LEVEL", "ID")
  .filter(col("LEVEL") > 1) // Remove root node from created rows
  .join(dataframe.select("PARENTID"), col("PARENTID") === col("ID"), "left_anti")
  // then create a row with a 'parent' with LEVEL = (current LEVEL - 1) and PARENTID = (current ID)
  .withColumnRenamed("ID", "PARENTID")
  .withColumn("LEVEL", col("LEVEL") - 1)
  // and take ID and NAME  
  .join(dataframe.select("NAME", "ID", "LEVEL"), Seq("LEVEL"))
  // such that the current ID < ID of the node from the LEVEL above.
  .filter(col("ID") < col("PARENTID"))

val result = dataframe
  .unionByName(createdRows)
  .orderBy("NAME", "PARENTID") // Optional, if you want an ordered result
```

And in `result` dataframe you get:

```
+----+---+--------+-----+
|NAME|ID |PARENTID|LEVEL|
+----+---+--------+-----+
|A1  |1  |2       |1    |
|B1  |2  |3       |2    |
|B1  |2  |18      |2    |
|C1  |18 |4       |3    |
|C2  |3  |5       |3    |
|C2  |3  |10      |3    |
|D1  |4  |null    |4    |
|D2  |5  |null    |4    |
|D3  |10 |11      |4    |
|E1  |11 |null    |5    |
+----+---+--------+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, good solution!